# Updating amount of "lifes" that the player has

Tags: actionscript

I'm making this small flash game where a user has to fly and try to dodge stuff... when the user hits an object it has to remove one of his lives that is shown by a feather.

Everything of the game works perfectly however the feathers don't want to update on the frame (they keep showing 3 which is the starting amount of lives).

This function adds the feathers (illustrating the lives of the player).

```
 var levens = 3;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leeft);

function leeft(evt:Event):void {
    for(var i = 0; i < levens; i++)
    {
    var v:MovieClip = new feather_mc();
    addChild(v);
    v.x = 50 + i*12; 
    v.y = 382;
    }

}
```

Following function is a hittest object function that updates the variable "levens"... as soon as the user hits an object

```
function raak(evt:Event):void {

    if(eagle_mc.hitTestPoint(evt.target.x,evt.target.y, true)==true)
    {
        removeChild(MovieClip(evt.target));
        evt.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,raak);
        levens--;
        if(levens==0)
        {
            gotoAndStop(41);
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are constantly adding new feathers since the "leeft" function is called on each frame. The result is that the feathers are stacked on top of each other, so if you remove one, the other at the same location appears. I suppose you'll want to execute this method once during initialization.